# How to merge two directories from a windows subversion in a linux subversion

Tags: svn, ubuntu-server

I have  subversion on Ubuntu server. Before installation of Ubuntu my professor used to have subversion directories and files on windows server. He used to use tortoisesvn to checkout and commit the files.  After the installation of Ubuntu server I had created a subversion directory to checkout,checkin my files onto the server. Now my professor wants to move those backed up directories and files onto my subversion on server. I tried importing those to the repository but those are being added as new files(checkout version 1). But there are different versions or files and directories existing in the windows subversion repository.
I am not sure if am clear but this is my situation. Can I dump the files, but since the whole directory is backed up and moved to the ubuntu server I am confused how to dump those files such that he will exactly has the same versions when he is checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to transfer a repository from one setup to another:

- Create a dump of the windows repo:

  ```
  svnadmin dump /path/to/windows-repo > windows.dump
  ```
- Create the new repo on your Unbuntu server:

  ```
  svnadmin create /path/to/ubuntu-repo
  ```
- Import the dump into the new ubuntu repo if the new repo is still empty:

  ```
  svnadmin load /path/to/ubuntu-repo < windows.dump
  ```

Please note that if you already have committed revisions in the new repository, the revision numbers of the imported repo won't be the same, and your professor will have to make a clean checkout. Also, I recommend to make a backup before running `svnadmin load`, just in case it doesn't turn out as you imagined and you need to add some [options](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) to the command, or read more [in-depth instructions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a dump of your professor's repo and load it in your's, giving a directory in your repo where you want to base your professor's repo files against

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repo/professorrepo > professor-dumpfile

svnadmin load /path/to/repo/yourrepo --parent-dir professor/ < professor-dumpfile
```

where `professor/` will be the root folder where the files from professor repo will be put in your repo.